# How to run php code only for a specific widget on a page and not all widgets on that page?

Tags: php, filters, widget-text

I want to display extra information below the post title only for the posts widget on the home page and not the portfolio widget. I'm using Wordpress' the_title filter to do this and that works fine, but at the moment, it shows the extra info in both the portfolio and the posts widgets. I need a condition to restrict the filtering only to the posts widget. The post widget's class name is "home-post-widget"

My current code looks like this.

```
function add_rating_html( $title) {

    if (in_the_loop()){
        $out = "Rating: 5";
        $title .= $out;
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'add_rating_html',1);
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `is_front_page()` and/or `is_home()` instead of `in_the_loop()`?

Comment: is_home() doesn't work, but is_front_page() does, which is much better than using in_the_loop(). Thanks :) But the problem is that both the portfolio and the posts block are on the front page, and I only want to show the rating in the posts block. With is_front_page(), it's showing the rating on both the portfolio and the posts block.

Comment: when you say the portfolio or posts block, do you mean widgets, or do you mean blocks, or do you mean blocks in a widget area? Widgets and blocks are not the same, you need to be very clear if you're referring to a block, or a widget. If it is indeed a block, then the answer to this question will be useless to you because you asked about widgets, not blocks. Also if you are referring to things in a page builder that's also super important to mention.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I shouldn't have used the word block. Both the portfolio and posts widgets are Elementor widgets. And yes I use the page builder Elementor Pro. I've updated the question to clarify that I'm referring to widgets.

Comment: I found a workaround for the time being, just enclosing the rating in a <p> tag and adding the following css to hide the <p> tag only in the portfolio where the rating is displayed. This still shows it in the posts widget where I want it. Of course, I'd rather save loading time and not print the rating in the portfolio at all.
.elementor-portfolio-item__title p {
 display: none !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's in a loop, you should be able to check against the type of post, and only add it to that type.

```
function add_rating_html( $title) {

    if ( is_front_page() && 'post' === get_post_type() ) {
        $out    = "Rating: 5";
        $title .= $out;
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_rating_html', 1 );
```

There's probably a better way to do it by hooking on to the specific widget, but I'm no expert with how Elementor works

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work because the post type in both the portfolio widget and the posts widget are of type 'post'.

Comment: Then you really need to find something better to manage portfolio items